# Insert data in MySQL Database using AJAX on checkbox tick

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, onclick

Before getting stuck here, I had a look at the implementation of question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29119988/insert-records-to-mysql-database-with-php-using-ajax)

I tried implementing the code and wish to insert data at checkbox click inside MySQL database. It might have been done already if I was supposed to insert data on form submission but I have to individually insert 8 bit data by turning their flag ON/OFF at checkbox tick.

I tried doing it, but don't know where exactly I am going wrong.

Below are the code snippets :

**PHP CODE insertIntoAbbaa.php :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php

    $updateCon = mysqli_connect("192.168.0.7", "uzer", "password", "remondb");
    if (!$updateCon) {
        die("not able to cconnect" . mysqli_error());
    }
    if(isset($_POST['firstOutputData'])){

        $firstData = mysqli_escape_string($updateCon, $_POST['firstOutputData']);

        if(!$firstData){
            echo "nopes !";
        }

        $updateValue = mysqli_query($updateCon, "INSERT INTO update_abbaa(rfu_id, upadate_index, update_value) values(1,'$firstData',1)");

        if(!$updateValue){
            echo "nopes !";
        }

        mysqli_close($dbget);
        echo "Saved !";
        }
    else{
        echo " nothing happened ! ";
    }
    ?>
</body>
```

Below is the onclick event I am calling on checkbox tick :

**HTML onclick code snippet :**

```
<span class="toggle">
  <input type="checkbox" onclick="onOffFunction1()" id="onoff1">
  <label data-off="Off" data-on="On"></label>
</span>
```

Now, I am trying to call the above mentioned function in javascript as follows :

```
function onOffFunction1() {
   var firstCb = document.getElementById("onoff1");

   if (firstCb.checked) {
       document.getElementById("firstBitData").innerHTML = "1";
       document.getElementById("firstBitData").style.backgroundColor = "green";
       var firstOutputData = "1";

 $.ajax({
       url: "insertIntoAbbaa.php",
       type : "POST",
       data : "firstOutputData"+firstOutputData,
       success: function(data)
         {
          alert("success !" + data);
         } 
     });

  }
```

The output shows me "nothing happened" message as I have written in PHP script

Please go easy on me I am a beginner !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message 'Nothing happened' is caused because this check:

`if(isset($_POST['firstOutputData']))`

is false. That means there is no value inside `$_POST` with index 'firstOutputData'. The first place you need to look for an error like that is your AJAX call and if you pass the parameter correctly, which you don't.

This:

`data : "firstOutputData"+firstOutputData,`

should be:

`data : {firstOutputData: firstOutputData}`

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! Thanks a lot !